# Selecting motors to lift 3 kg

Tags: motors

I need a little guidance to select a motor for a lifting mechanism for a weight of 3 kg. I am going to use two motors and both motors will have a gear (attached to the shaft) very close to each other and in between the gears, a thick rope will be placed so that the gears will bite into the rope and then move up. Each of the motors needs to lift 1.5 kg (hence a total of 3 kg).
To JUST counter the downforce of 2 kg (20 N) I need two motors of 3 kg-cm so if I use two motors of 5 kg-cm (@150 rpm) the payload will start moving up? Please tell me if I am right or wrong. Thank you.

my calculations:
2 kg

down force 2 X 9.8 = 19.6 N ~ **20 N**

radius = 3 cm

torque  = 20 X 0.03 = 0.6 N-m = 6.114 kg-cm [1 Newton meter is equal to 10.19 kg-cm].

i.e Each motor capable of giving **3** kg-cm.

Comment: At what speed do you want to lift the weight? That will tell you the power needed. What is the gear ratio? That will tell you how much to multiply the motor torque by. Or are you saying that the rope will be gripped by the teeth of the gears which are directly attached to the motor shafts? Adding a diagram of the arrangement to the question would make that clear. (It won't show at first: a user with editing privileges will add it for you.)

Comment: I recommend picking a motor based on size and your gut, and then doing the math from there to see where you end up. Don't forget that it's cheaper to waste a little money overbuilding a machine than it is to underbuild and have to start over. If the speed doesn't matter you can always increase the torque with gears.

Comment: 2kg or 3kg? Which or just the highest?

Comment: This is only the first step to determine the minimum motor capacity required to initiate the motion with no speed, and the motor might just stop spinning after the weight has left the support base/ground. Then the weight may fall back down as the motor has burned out.  Please provide more details of the intended application and the end goal, so people can provide more pointed answers.

Comment: @abhiramAnne what is the gear ratio (or what are the teeth for the gear pair) and what is the pitch of the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your gear radius is 3cm and you want to be able to lift 1.5kg you need a motor with
$$ \tau> (1.5+ \text{weight of the rope say 0.5kg})*3 \quad \rightarrow \tau> 6 kg-cm \quad torque.$$

But because your gears will bite with uneven force into the rope you want to consider the friction and the irregular grip of the gear's teeth. I would double the torque to 12kg-cm.

If you need a rough estimate for the acceleration up we subtract the part of torque balancing the wight of 2kg, the rest acts to accelerate the object and rope

$$F = (12 - 6)kg-cm/(3cm)=2kg=20N \quad \alpha=20/2kg=10m/s^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Most of the motors has this curve, let's map the axis as an example:
[image: Motor curve]

map in x's axis, 8.7 -> 5kgf (1.67kgf at 3cm radius) -> 1.5kgf would be 90%.

map in y's axis 100rpm -> 150rpm (take 100 as percentage)

Supposing increasing 1% in torque is a decreasing of 1% in velocity (with axis as percentages of the maximum)

Then you would have 10% of the 150rpm maximum, it is 15rpm, with 3cm would be 15*2$\pi$*0.03/60= 0.04712m/s upward.

With your motor capacities of 3kgf you would be using 100% of the torque, then 0% of velocity.

This is a linear approximation, the motors have a dead zone so be sure that your percentage velocity isn't inside that dead zone (in which the motor wouldn't move on because of static friction), I had a pololu motor with 1.8kgf it was 20% dead zone as reference specially if it has weight on it.